# Unresolved symbols from d3dx10math.h after moving from DX10 to DX11

Tags: c++, visual-studio, directx, linker-errors, directxmath

I have updated my DirectX 10 project to DirectX 11 (using DirectX SDK) and suddenly it fails at linker stage because all methods from d3dx10math header, like `D3DXMatrixMultiply()` or `D3DXVec3TransformCoord()`, became unresolved symbols.

Some of them come from files which I didn't even touch. All I've done was changing D3DX10 and D3D10 headers to DX11 and adding device context and relevant methods for interfacing with the shaders. My project setting also didn't change and I have DirectX `include` and `lib` folders added to VC++ Directories.

Any clue on what may be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing `#pragma comment(lib, "d3dx10.lib")`. turns out you need to include both libraries for DX10 and DX11.